# Failed MSSQL Backup Restoration Due to Defunct State in a File: How to Resolve?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I'm having trouble restoring an MSSQL backup because one of the files is in a defunct state. I need help fixing this to complete the restoration. Thank you!
Additionally, my MSSQL backup restoration reaches 99% progress, but then it fails. I'm not sure what to do next. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I've been attempting to remove the issue to proceed with the restoration. I'm using SQL 2014 on the source machine and aiming to restore the backup on a SQL Server 2017 machine.

Additionally, I found a related issue that may be connected to my problem, and it appears to have been fixed in a Microsoft support article: [KB3009576 - Cannot Restore Database with Defunct Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb3009576-fix-cannot-restore-database-by-using-the-full-backup-and-differential-backup-files-that-contain-defunct-files-7d9b266f-0a8d-f597-503b-65e4fbe51346). However, I'm still encountering difficulties.

the command is:

```
restore database sampleDatabase from disk = 'D:\Customer-backup\new.bak' with move 'sample' TO 'D:\Customer-backup\sampleDatabase.mdf', move 'sample_large_db' TO 'D:\Customer-backup\sampleDatabase_large_db.ndf', move 'sample_log' TO 'D:\Customer-backup\sampleDatabase_log.ldf', STATS = 1
```

and the last log that i think is relevant to problem is:

> Date 9/19/2023 10:11:53 AM 
> Log SQL Server (Current - 9/19/2023
> 10:18:00 AM) 
> Source spid73 
> Message External dump process return code
> 0x20000001. 
> External dump process returned no errors.

Using `restore filelistonly from disk='...'` command, I noticed that the 'IsPresent' value for certain NDF files is false, which could be insightful.

| LogicalName | PhysicalName | Type | FileGroupName | Size | MaxSize | FileId | CreateLSN | DropLSN | UniqueId | ReadOnlyLSN | ReadWriteLSN | BackupSizeInBytes | SourceBlockSize | FileGroupId | LogGroupGUID | DifferentialBaseLSN | DifferentialBaseGUID | IsReadOnly | IsPresent | TDEThumbprint | SnapshotUrl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample | E:\Customer-backup\sample_0.mdf | D | PRIMARY | 15801843712 | 35184372080640 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 9B49836A-5B02-4D6B-A163-746665E8803D | 0 | 0 | 12389580800 | 512 | 1 | NULL | 78738000000546700284 | C917BFF2-276D-449A-ACB1-0887C31E6309 | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| sample_large_db1 | E:\Customer-backup\sample_0.ndf | D | LARGE_DB | 0 | 35184372080640 | 3 | 519000001077600001 | 0 | 2497E2C6-5607-403A-A299-8762FC8B1872 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 512 | 2 | NULL | 1007000004570500045 | 1A03C813-A6B9-433F-8342-9A596FBFEF34 | 0 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| sample_large_db | E:\Customer-backup\sample\sample_1.ndf | D | LARGE_DB | 2147483648 | 35184372080640 | 4 | 711000000500500001 | 0 | 4DA939C6-1D71-451C-A22F-B46403BF9713 | 0 | 0 | 2424832 | 512 | 2 | NULL | 78738000000546700284 | C917BFF2-276D-449A-ACB1-0887C31E6309 | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| sample_log | E:\Customer-backup\sample\sample_2.ldf | L | NULL | 220790784 | 2199023255552 | 2 | 0 | 0 | BFA2E756-B483-4946-BC5E-0FA7471B2D0B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 512 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: what's the command and exact errors you are getting

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you please [edit] your question and add the details (**restore"" command and **error message**) from the comment to the question? It makes for really better reading. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnK.N.
Thank you for the warm welcome to the DBA.SE community. I maked this improvement. Thanks.

Comment: @siggemannen
I improved the question with adding **restore command** and **error message**

Comment: no one has no idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I successfully resolved it by following these steps:**

1. Initially, I accessed the attached database and copied its physical files to another server.
2. When attempting to attach the database to the new server, an error was encountered regarding missing *.ndf files. To address this dependency, I created a copy of an existing .ndf file and renamed it, allowing the successful attachment of the database.
3. However, while attempting to create a backup, a new error occurred with the message:

```
I/O error 23 (Data error (cyclic redundancy check)) detected during read at offset 0x000001ac1c4000 in file ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2K16\MSSQL\DATA\MoreData.mdf’.
```

4. To resolve this, I opted to create a new simple database and export all tables to it.